# Nodejs HTTP Request ERRCONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to start building node apps and having trouble with my instance.

After working with `require('http').get(...)` for some time and having no success, I decided to try the example from the API docs as follows.

```
var http=require('http')
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message); 
});
```

[http.get api, Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

and for every single time that I have tried I receive an error saying `ECONNREFUSED`

More detailed error object below;

```
 Got error: 
 { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

`
I really don't know why this is and I get the same error message for every single host I try, even localhost/127.0.0.1, www.google.com, www.example.com

uname -a

`Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Fri Mar 20 20:43:59 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

node -v

`v0.6.12`

npm -v

`1.1.4`

Comment: How do I vote your comment down?

Comment: you can flag it if you want

Answer (score 0):

After updating my Node to a more recent version I can use require('http').get(...) successfully.